# Replacing a specific character in a string with another character in MIPS

Tags: mips, mips32

I'm writing a program in mips that takes a string and replaces a specific character in it with another.
At first, I didn't check if the input string is legal(but I check if the input character is legal) and it worked fine. Then I tried to do the legality check for the string but it turned out that what I stored in $a1(the register I used to store the string) would be covered by the subsequent input character. However, I didn't even use $a1 for the latter code so I'm now really confused.

Here is my code:

```
.data
    inputa:         .asciiz"Input string in register A (press enter to finish): "
    inputb:         .asciiz"Input character in register B (press enter to finish): "
    inputc:         .asciiz"Input character in register C (press enter to finish): "
    outputa:        .asciiz"Output string in register A: "
    addr:           .space 0x0000000
                    .text
                    .globl main
    
    main:           
    
    input_a:        la $a0, inputa
                    li $v0, 4
                    syscall                     #Prompt "Input string in register A (press enter to finish): "
                    la $a0, addr                #Load another address to $a0 so that the following code won't change the content in inputa
                    li $v0, 8                   
                    syscall                     #Read the input
                    move $s0, $a0               #Make a copy of the string and store it in $s0
                    li $t1, -1                  #Use $t1 as a counter for the length of the input and initialize it as -1
    
    count_a:        addi $t1, $t1, 1            #Add the counter by 1 each round
                    lb $t0, 0($a0)              #Store the first character of the current string in $t0
                    addi $a0, $a0, 1            #Move to the next character of the string
                    beq $t0, $0, count_a_finish #If the first character is null (i.e. the string reaches the end), jump out of count_a
                    j count_a                   #Otherwise jump back to count_a
    
    count_a_finish: beq $t1, 1, input_a         #If the input is of length 1(i.e. "\n") then the input is legal, otherwise ask the user to input once again
                    move $a1, $s0               #Store the string in $a1
    
    input_b:        la $a0, inputb
                    li $v0, 4
                    syscall                     #Prompt "Input character in register B (press enter to finish): "
                    la $a0, addr                #Load another address to $a0 so that the following code won't change the content in inputb
                    li $v0, 8                   
                    syscall                     #Read the input
                    lb $s0, 0($a0)              #Make a copy of the first character of the input and store it in $s0
                    li $t1, -1                  #Use $t1 as a counter for the length of the input and initialize it as -1
    
    count_b:        addi $t1, $t1, 1            #Add the counter by 1 each round
                    lb $t0, 0($a0)              #Store the first character of the current string in $t0
                    addi $a0, $a0, 1            #Move to the next character of the string
                    beq $t0, $0, count_b_finish #If the first character is null (i.e. the string reaches the end), jump out of count_b 
                    j count_b                   #Otherwise jump back to count_b
    
    count_b_finish: bne $t1, 2, input_b         #If the input is of length 2(i.e. a character and '\n') then the input is legal, otherwise ask the user to input once again
                    move $a2, $s0               #Store the character to be modified in $a2
    
    input_c:        la $a0, inputc
                    li $v0, 4
                    syscall                     #Prompt "Input character in register B (press enter to finish): "
                    la $a0, addr                #Load another address to $a0 so that the following code won't change the content in inputb
                    li $v0, 8
                    syscall                     #Read the input
                    lb $s0, 0($a0)              #Make a copy of the first character of the input and store it in $s0
                    li $t1, -1                  #Use $t1 as a counter for the length of the input and initialize it as -1
    
    count_c:        addi $t1, $t1, 1            #Add the counter by 1 each round
                    lb $t0, 0($a0)              #Store the first character of the current string in $t0
                    addi $a0, $a0, 1            #Move to the next character of the string
                    beq $t0, $0, count_c_finish #If the character is null (i.e. the input reaches the end) jump out of count_c
                    j count_c 
    
    count_c_finish: bne $t1, 2, input_c         #If the input is of length 2(i.e. a character and '\n') then the input is legal, otherwise ask the user to input once again
                    move $a3, $s0               #Store the character to be modified in $a3
                    
                    la $a0, outputa
                    li $v0, 4
                    syscall                     #Prompt "Output string in register A: "
                    jal replace                 #Call "replace"
    
    print:          addi $sp, $sp, -8           #Space for two words
                    lb $a0, 0($sp)              #Load the stored character to $a0
                    li $v0, 11
                    syscall                     #Print the character
                    beq $a0, 0, exit            #If the character is '\0', goto "exit"
                    j print                     #Jump back to "print" unconditionally
    
    exit:           li $v0, 10                  
                    syscall                     #Terminate the program
    
    replace:        lb $t0, 0($a1)              #Load the first character in $a1 to $t0
                    beq $t0, 0, replace_return  #If the character is '\0', goto "exit"
                    addi $sp, $sp, -8           #Space for two words
                    sw $ra, 4($sp)              #Store return address
                    beq $t0, $a2, use_new       #If the character is equal to the character to be modified, goto "use_new"
                    sb $t0, 0($sp)              #Store the original character 
                    j next_char                 #Jump to "next_char" unconditionally
    
    use_new:        sb $a3, 0($sp)              #Store the new character
    
    next_char:      addi $a1,$a1, 1             #Store the address of the next character
                    jal replace                 #Call "replace"
    
    replace_return: lw $ra, 4($sp)              #Load return address
                    addi $sp, $sp, 8            #Restore $sp
                    jr $ra                      #Back to caller
```

Comment: `$a1` doesn't contain the actual string data. It contains the address of the string data. And it looks like you're overwriting that same portion of memory with the other system calls. I don't understand why you're uising system call 8 for reading single characters though, instead of just using system call 12.

Comment: I have also tried using other registers such as $t3 to replace $a1 but it didn't seem to work as well.

Comment: As for the system call, I use 8 because it's a part of my coursework and my teacher asks me not to use 12 so that I shall detect inllegal input manually.

Comment: Which registers you use isn't important here. The problem is that you're re-using the exact same portion of memory for all inputs, so of course they're going to overwrite eachother.  If you don't want that to happen, then use different addresses for each `read_string` system call. Also, `.space 0x0000000` is incorrect. Instead of 0 you should specify a size that's sufficiently large to hold all the data that you want to store in that buffer.

Comment: Got it. I have now fixed my code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A new question came to me. Though all my operations were done in the address stored in $a0, after each operation I have stored the result I want in other registers(i.e. $a1, $a2, $a3). So why would the value stored in $a1, $a2 and $a3 be affected by the latter operations in $a0.  (I have tested that operation move only gave the value but not the address of the value so I think what's already in $a1, $a2, $a3 can't be influenced by $a0.)

Comment: `$a1` hold the address of a string.